# Export recursively a package and all its subpackages in a osgi manifest

Tags: java, manifest

I have a Java manifest that must export an API. It contains a row where I describe the package.

I export:

```
Export-Package: a.b.c.pack
```

If I want to export the subpackage `a.b.c.pack.d1`, I should add this:

```
Export-Package: a.b.c.pack, a.b.c.pack.d1
```

But if I add many other packages it can become a problem.

How can I do to say: hey, I just want to export a.b.c.pack and all its sub-packages as well?

Answer (score 3):

According to the OSGI spec, you can't.

Reference:

- [OSGi Core release 7 - 3.6.5 Export-Package](http://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.module.html#framework.module.exportpackage)

---

But this is entirely consistent with Java semantics.  Java packages do not nest.  The idea of a "subpackage" does not exist in the semantics<sup>1</sup> of Java.  For instance, there is no way to import "a package and its subpackages" or extend package-private access to "subpackages".

<sup>1 - The JLS only uses the term "subpackage" in the context of the formation and meaning of fully qualified names.  There is no semantic associated ... apart from meaning of the name itself.</sup>